# how to uninstall spree_fancy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I am trying out spree rails gem. I followed their tutorial and added spree_fancy gem. How do I uninstall spree_fancy and go back to the old look? I commented out spree_fancy in the gemFile, but now I get errors on the page. Just commenting out and running bundle install does not remove the customizations done by spree_fancy. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the installation guide backwards - undo each step from end to start.

Comment: Thank you that worked. I had to google how to reverse rails generate. Then removed the requirement from the gemfile and ran bundle:install. Rails is nice :).

Comment: This is way easier with git, but only if you just commit often. Then you can revert any given commit, so added files are removed (or reverted if were just changed)

Comment: Could you post how you did it exactly for future users with the same problem. Like me at this moment :)